# Response time of a research supervisor

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, etiquette

I had an informal interview with a foreign professor on Skype and things went well. We talked on Friday and he said he will discuss my case during the meeting for recruitment of students. He showed interest and we exchanged emails for the possibilities of scholarships. Mean while he even sent me a book and lecture related to work but he did not replied my email on Monday. I thought he must be busy due to his meeting and its Thursday and still have not heard from him. Tomorrow it will be a week of my interview. Its just 2 or 3 days but should I be worried or wait, until he gets back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sara, I would wait another working day (Friday), and on upcoming Monday morning, I would send the following email, so the he/she could respond the beginning of the next week:

```
Dear Prof.X

I would appreciate if you could let me know about the outcome of the interview?

Kind Regards, 
Sara
```

Comment: My interview went well and he seemed to be happy. The only thing worries me he said he will take my case to a meeting on Tuesday. May be he is busy. I have already sent him a similar email. Last week he was responding me within 10 to 15 mins and this week nothing.

Comment: @Sarazahoor Academics have busy schedules, and of course it is your life priority to get the position, but the academics have other priorities as well. Being patient is key here.